# How to have two sections using 50% of the total height?

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

My goal is to have two sections, both containing a methodbar and table, which are using all the height available.

Any idea about how to modify the CSS?
I already tried playing with `height` and `100%` on `body` and `50%` on a custom tag but with no luck.

Here's a JSFiddle sample, including Bootstrap: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFabio80/ebd54dtt/)

---

*Code Snippet:*

```css
.browsehappy {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */

.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Custom page header */

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */

.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}
/* Custom page footer */

.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
/* Main marketing message and sign up button */

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}
/* Supporting marketing content */

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}
/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
/* customizations */

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  /*
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
*/
}
.collapsed {
  display: none;
  /* hide it for small displays */
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .collapsed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -25%;
    /* same width as sidebar */
  }
}
#row-main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* necessary to hide collapsed sidebar */
}
#content {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
#sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease;
}
.methodbar {} .sidebar-section {
  height: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="row-main">
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <div class="row sidebar-section">
        <div class="methodbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <table class="row table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="row sidebar-section">
        <div class="methodbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="content">

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>'Allo, 'Allo!</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          <img src="images/yeoman.png" alt="I'm Yeoman">
          <br>Always a pleasure scaffolding your apps.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#/">Splendid!<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row marketing">
        <h4>HTML5 Boilerplate</h4>
        <p>HTML5 Boilerplate is a professional front-end template for building fast, robust, and adaptable web apps or sites.</p>
        <h4>Angular</h4>
        <p>AngularJS is a toolset for building the framework most suited to your application development.</p>
        <h4>Karma</h4>
        <p>Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the `vh` unit, `50vh`

Comment: It is required that you supply a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here, not some third-party site that may change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for pointing this, here's the the link on [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably presented in a [**Code Snippet**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the viewport measuring unit for height. Change the sidebar-section css to following:

```
.sidebar-section {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

100vh setting specifies that the height should take the full screen so we set the section to take 50vh so that the 2 sections will take the full viewable space. It is just like 100% only that it takes into account only the area that is visible on the screen based on whatever screen size it becomes.

Comment: incredible, never heard yet about vieport unit. Thanks a lot Nasir!!

Answer (score 1):

I made an example. There is no need to use bootstrap, you can use the `vh` unit (viewport height). `height: 50vh` will set the height to 50% of the viewport height (The whole screen). Hopefully this works! Good luck!

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 50vh; /*THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART OF THE CODE*/
  width: 100%;

}
#div2 {
  background-color: deeppink;
  height: 50vh; /*THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART OF THE CODE*/
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [**flexbox**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

There are many resources here in [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/search), many of them are well written by [@Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b).

---

In your particular case, complete the following steps to achieve the desired result:

- Make your `#row-main` a flex-container that can wrap its content. This will make its children flex-items.
- Make your `.sidebar`, which is now a flex-item, a flex-container as well, but with column direction.
- Distribute the space available inside `.sidebar` flex-container, using `flex: 1;` in `.sidebar-section` flex-items.

---

*Code Snippet:*

```css
.browsehappy {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */

.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Custom page header */

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */

.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}
/* Custom page footer */

.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
/* Main marketing message and sign up button */

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}
/* Supporting marketing content */

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}
/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
/* customizations */

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  /*
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
*/
}
.collapsed {
  display: none;
  /* hide it for small displays */
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .collapsed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -25%;
    /* same width as sidebar */
  }
}
#row-main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* necessary to hide collapsed sidebar */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#content {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
#sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar-section {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="row-main">
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <div class="row sidebar-section">
        <div class="methodbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <table class="row table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="row sidebar-section">
        <div class="methodbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="content">

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>'Allo, 'Allo!</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          <img src="images/yeoman.png" alt="I'm Yeoman">
          <br>Always a pleasure scaffolding your apps.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#/">Splendid!<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row marketing">
        <h4>HTML5 Boilerplate</h4>
        <p>HTML5 Boilerplate is a professional front-end template for building fast, robust, and adaptable web apps or sites.</p>
        <h4>Angular</h4>
        <p>AngularJS is a toolset for building the framework most suited to your application development.</p>
        <h4>Karma</h4>
        <p>Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**[Revised jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/wLgzu6h2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ricky_Ruiz !

Comment: @Micky Have in mind that using viewport units will not render the elements to occupy `100%` of the container. They will ocuppy `100vh` of said viewport, if you scroll, which in your case there is no more content causing overflow and no scroll is visible, those elements will not be big enough.